# Select safari management

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Good day. Tell me how can I turn off the arrows in Safari

[image]

Comment: Why? Those arrows help you navigate between form elements. I think you would have to remove the selects from the enclosing form. That will lower accessibility. I dont suggest doing it.

Comment: I don’t think you can. Even if there are no other form elements the arrows stay, but are greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

I decided by adding to the `select`

```
tabindex="-1"
```

Comment: Don't do this. You've now made the input non-selectable and inaccessible for keyboard/accessible users. Which in some countries is illegal and can get you fined.

Comment: Interesting. I will look for another option

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad-news. I would suggest letting the client know that OS arrows aren't controllable by a website.

Comment: Maybe someone came across how to configure the control of these buttons.